# Setup SSH keys to login as super user

Tags: ssh, sudo, su

I have a random question. I am new to SysAdmin side, so not sure if I am doing it right way or not.

We have a sudo user setup called wladmin an host1. I login to host 1 as myself, then do following to execute scripts owned by wladmin. 
sudo su - wladmin
Pass my own password again.
and execute scripts.

Now, I want to setup ssh keys, in between myself@host2 and  wladmin@host1. I put id_rsa.pub from myself@host2 in the authorized_keys of wladmin@host1. But it's not working.
When I am trying to do ssh wladmin@host1 from host2 as myself, I am getting prompt for password. 
Any idea, how to resolve it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You transfer the key with ssh-copy-id and then when you ssh in you ssh -i ~/.ssh/key_name user@server. If it is not working , update your question with the output of `ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/key_name user@server` Last, are you using an encrypted home directory ? See also http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_keys

Comment: So, here is main problem. I am not able to use the command " ssh-copy-id wladmin@host1". It's popping up for password. 
I have the root access on host1. I changed the password of wladmin by using following command on host1: 
passwd wladmin1
I tried doing " ssh wladmin@host" from host2. On prompt, I entered the password for msp. And I am getting "Permission Denied"

I am guessing there is some config on host2, which is not allowing me to login directly as wladmin. Its only allowing me to become wladmin bu using "sudo su - wladmin" on host2 and passing my own password.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: I can not paste the Output of 
ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub msp@amfb2uat04 its too long. Here are the last few lines:

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1477
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password

Comment: Use a pastebin for the output. You need to know wladmin's password, you can set one with passwd . Otherwise, manually set up the key. I covered manual setup and permissions in my link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I setup my passwordless login.

I log in to Host2 and create a key

```
$ ssh myself@host2
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And follow the prompts. When you are finished you have created your local key and now we need to get it onto the server.

To get it onto the server we use the command `ssh-copy-id` like so

```
$ ssh-copy-id wladmin@host1
```

This will prompt for the wladmin users password.This command will send your key to the server and set you up for passwordless login.

This is all assuming host1 and host2 are linux boxes.

Comment: IMO it is extremely helpful to give each ssh key a unique name. You also need to specify a key with ssh-copy-id assuming you have more then one key. After transferring the key, it is often helpful to disable password authentication.

Comment: So, here is main problem. I have the root access on host1. I changed the password of wladmin. by using following command: passwd